# Yoast SEO Как поставить meta Title и Description для кастомной страницы Archive

Tags: php, wordpress, meta, yoast

Столкнулся с проблемой что для костюмных страниц произвольного типа записи (в моем случаи `online-ports` ) не выводиться SEO атрибуты необходимые для продвижения данных страниц.

В просторах интернета нашел решение, что эти параметры необходимо задавать не в Рубрике кастомной записи (что казалось бы очевидным), а в настройках самого плагина

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше удалось найти, что эти параметры можно получить через

```
$titles = get_option( 'wpseo_titles' );

$title  = $titles['title-online-ports'];
$description = $titles['metadesc-online-ports'];
```

Но вот как добиться того что бы в head для данного типа отображались эти значения, пока не могу понять.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
</head>
```

Подскажите, как их добавлять? Нужно ли правки делать в файле `header.php` или можно в `archive-online-ports.php` какие-то проверки добавить ?

Comment: Походу не там заполнил, на скрине где ты показал это для кастомных сингл записей. Для главного архива поля там же только чуть ниже  SEO title и Meta description. Для категорий в самих категорий сео пишется, для синг в самих сингл. Нигде ничего добавлять не надо, проверил у себя.

Answer (score 1):

тебе надо зарегистрировать переменную для этого твоего Юстаса
и только потом можешь туда добавлять требуемый контент
в настройках Юстаса вставлять в формате %%desc_from_post%%

```
//переменная для вставки в шаблоны Yoast( например для мета-тега description )
function register_post_desc_for_yoast() {
   wpseo_register_var_replacement( '%%desc_from_post%%', 'post_desc_for_yoast', 'advanced', 'it is post desc for yoast' );
}
function post_desc_for_yoast() {
   //раскомментить что нужно
   //return get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'title-of-metro', true);
   //return get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
   //return apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id));
}  
add_action('wpseo_register_extra_replacements', 'register_post_desc_for_yoast');
```

**Yoast зло**, если ты, как и большинство начинашек, используешь его только для мета-тегов, забив на остальные 98% функционала, то разумнее решить 12 строчками кода в functions.php без загрузки этого монстра по пожиранию серверных мощностей...
Да, кстати, вышеприведенный код вставлять сюда - functions.php